# bytewise compare varint encoded int64's

Tags: go, byte

I'm using [levigo](https://github.com/jmhodges/levigo), the leveldb bindings for Go. My keys are `int64`'s and need to be kept sorted. By default, leveldb uses a bytewise comparator so I'm trying to use varint encoding.

```
func i2b(x int64) []byte {
    b := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
    n := binary.PutVarint(b, x)
    return key[:n]
}
```

My keys are not being sorted correctly. I wrote the following as a test.

```
var prev int64 = 0
for i := int64(1); i < 1e5; i++ {
    if bytes.Compare(i2b(i), i2b(prev)) <= 0 {
        log.Fatalf("bytewise: %d > %d", b2i(prev), i)
    }
    prev = i
}
```

**output:** `bytewise: 127 > 128`

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/H8xTjlfRh8)

I'm not sure where the problem is. Am I doing the encoding wrong? Is varint not the right encoding to use?

**EDIT:**

BigEndian fixed width encoding is bytewise comparable

```
func i2b(x int64) []byte {
  b := make([]byte, 8)
  binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b, uint64(x))
  return b
}
```

Comment: reversing `key[:n]` before returning it will yield the correct result.  I don't have an explanation as to why, though.

Comment: probably you're right

Comment: @Tom: That doesn't work for all integers. You'll get e.g. (IINM) -3 > -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varint encoding is not bytewise comparable* wrt to the order of the values it caries. One option how to write the ordering/collating function (`cmp` bellow) is for example:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/binary"
        "log"
)

func i2b(x int64) []byte {
        var b [binary.MaxVarintLen64]byte
        return b[:binary.PutVarint(b[:], x)]
}

func cmp(a, b []byte) int64 {
        x, n := binary.Varint(a)
        if n < 0 {
                log.Fatal(n)
        }

        y, n := binary.Varint(b)
        if n < 0 {
                log.Fatal(n)
        }

        return x - y
}

func main() {
        var prev int64 = 0
        for i := int64(1); i < 1e5; i++ {
                if cmp(i2b(i), i2b(prev)) <= 0 {
                        log.Fatal("fail")
                }
                prev = i
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FArJnVsdxC)

(*) The reason is (also) the bit [fiddling performed](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/varint.go#L76).

Comment: is there an encoding that will preserve the underlying values's ordering?

Comment: @iliacholy: Of course, for example fixed size with the proper endianess. Or eg. variable length with a small log(value) prefix. One can invent endless of them. However, the [u]varint encoding is more space efficient then all of the above examples, especially for small numbers which occur quite often in real world scenarios.